# Simulate an NVA Appliance in Azure that forwards traffic with an Ubuntu VM

Tags: networking, server, vpn, iptables, azure

In Azure, I have 3 VirtualNetworks, A, B and C. A and B are peered to C.

I have an Ubuntu VM in all 3 of them.

I would like to have the VMs in VirtualNetworks A and B, be able to talk to one another by going through VirtualNetwork C.

Traditionally one could setup an AzureFirewall NVA, to route traffic from 1one Vnet to another.

I would like to know if its possible to use an Ubuntu VM in VirtualNetwork C, to act as a NVA and forward traffic from A <-> B.

I see past attempts [here](https://www.simplehelp.net/2009/04/15/how-to-redirect-traffic-to-another-machine-in-linux/) and [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/907972/route-all-traffic-of-a-machine-through-another-within-a-subnet), but they are not within an Azure network. Is this possible?

```
┌─────────────┐        ┌──────────────┐        ┌─────────────────┐
│ vnet-B      │        │vnet-C        │        │ Vnet-A          │
│             │        │    ┌──────┐  │        │   ┌──────┐      │
│  ┌──────┐   ├────────┤    │ VM-C │  ├────────┤   │VM-A  │      │
│  │ VM-B │   │ peering│    └──────┘  │peering │   │      │      │
│  └──────┘   │        │              │        │   └──────┘      │
│             │        │              │        │                 │
└─────────────┘        └──────────────┘        └─────────────────┘
```

Ideally I would have Nginx servers running on A and B and would be able to `curl` each one from each VM's CLI, and the traffic would pass through VM-C.